# Socket.io not working on aws with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am trying to connect to socket on aws ec2 instance. For some reason I am not able to do so . My client side code is  :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://ec2-MY-IP.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000');
            console.log(socket);
                    socket.on('connect', function(){
                      alert(socket.id); // 'G5p5...
                    });
   socket.on('connect_error', function(){
                console.log('Connection Failed');
            });
```

I Always get "Connection Failed" In browser console

I have opened the port from the security group's Inbound section and when I use :

```
 telnet ec2-MY-IP.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 3000
```

It gives me output

```
 Trying ...
 Connected to ec2-MY-IP.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

My server Side Code goes HERE :

```
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
 const app = express();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('listening on 3000');
  });
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://ec2-MY-IP.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/userlogsdemo', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
 db = database;
console.log("DB CONNECTED")
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("SOCKET CONNECTED")
    socketobj = socket
     socket.on('reloadtickets', function (data) {
    connectedusers.forEach(function(v){
            if(v.connecteduserid == data.target){ 
                setTimeout(function () {
                   io.emit('reloadticketsok',data );
                }, 100)


            }
        });
});
 // WHEN SOMEONE IS DISCONNECTED


 }); 

 })
```

When I RUN "node server.js" It says "DB CONNECTED" but not "SOCKET CONNECTED".
Code with localhost:8080(ON my local machine not on aws) works properly. Is there Anything special required to be done on aws Ec2. Any suggestions will be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you can check.

1. How you configured your security groups. Please verify once :
   You should select 'Custom TCP Rule' Port Range 3000 (as per your code), Source you can select anywhere(for testing).
2. You should check whether port 3000 is opened on linux(aws) firewall. To allow you can run :

   ```
   sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
   ```

Let's take a closer look at the above command.  We know what the iptables is in the command, thats the binary or program itself, now let's look at the other options.

-I stands for insert.  This will insert the rule at the top of the chain.  You can also use -A for append, which will place the new rule at the end of the chain.

INPUT tells the iptables command which chain you want the rule entered into.

-p tcp tells the rule to match only packets using the TCP protocol.

--dport 80 says to match traffic headed for port 80, or http.  --dport stands for destination port.

-j stands for JUMP to jump to the specified action or chain. In our case we are using -j ACCEPT so it will jump to the ACCEPT action and allow the traffic through.

Comment: I think Problem was with opening port. Solved! Thanks!

Comment: Is this sort of insecure? Should I close the port when I'm not using it?

Answer (score -1):

You should be open your port for socket on which its running
Lets you are using port 8890
**sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8890 -j ACCEPT**